# CUPS print file segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cups

I am trying to make a CUPS print system. I want to get printer status, how many pages printed sofar etc.

To do that, I am executing example programs given in CUPS examples.

```
#include <cups/cups.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

int num_options;
cups_option_t *options;

cups_dest_t *dests;
int num_dests = cupsGetDests(&dests);
cups_dest_t *dest = cupsGetDest("name", NULL, num_dests, dests);
int job_id;

/* Print a single file */
job_id = cupsPrintFile(dest->name, "testfile.txt", "Test Print", num_options, options);

cupsFreeDests(num_dests, dests);

return 0;
}
```

I compile it using    `gcc myfile.c -o myout -lcups`

When I try to execute `./myout`

I am getting

> Segmentation fault

I am using Raspberry-pi 3 board as my CUPS server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does gdb exist in your development environment?

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b yes.

Comment: If you know how to run it, it will break at the SIGSEGV, and the `where` command will give a stack-trace for where execution was when it segv'd.  Better if you compile in debug mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dest` is pointing to non-valid address.

```
cups_dest_t *dest; // declared but not initialized or assigned afterwards
```

So dereferencing it ( `cupsPrintFile(dest->name`... ) is UB and can cause SegFault.

---

This is how you should have used it (taken from [here](https://www.cups.org/doc/api-cups.html)):

```
#include <cups/cups.h>

cups_dest_t *dests;
int num_dests = cupsGetDests(&dests);
cups_dest_t *dest = cupsGetDest("name", NULL, num_dests, dests);

/* do something with dest */

cupsFreeDests(num_dests, dests);
```

---

**Update:**

Your code doesn't handle some of the variables (i.e. leaves them uninitialized - bad). The first one I see is `cups_option_t *options;`. Take care of all of your variables, and if that's not working - debug.

```
int main(){

int num_options;
cups_option_t *options; // add a call to "cupsAddOption("first", "value", num_options, &options);"

cups_dest_t *dests;
int num_dests = cupsGetDests(&dests);
cups_dest_t *dest = cupsGetDest("name", NULL, num_dests, dests);
int job_id;

/* Print a single file */
job_id = cupsPrintFile(dest->name, "testfile.txt", "Test Print", num_options, options); // options is used here but is uninitialized

cupsFreeDests(num_dests, dests);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed. But they are not derefernced from the code snippet OP provided (only [possibly] inside the function). The UB I mentioned occurs before the function is invoked

Comment: @CIsForCookies question updated with the latest code.

Comment: @CIsForCookies so how to solve this `cups_option_t *options;` initialization problem?

Comment: By carefully reading the link I provided. It shows the whole API with fine examples

Comment: @CIsForCookies That's what I had been doing for last 2 days. still this `Segmentation fault` error problem.